# Reading and writing XLS files

Tags: c#, .net, import, export, xls

Im searching for a .Net component to read and write xls files from an application in working on. I dont want use automation with Excel.

It should support reading and write Excel 97 and newer versions. And it would be great if its open source or free since its a very low budget project.

I have found this one: [MyXLS](http://myxls.in2bits.org/) that looks very promising.

Do you know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This must be one of the most asked questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+c%23+export).

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) reads and writes CSV / XLS / XLSX and does more.

You can see live ASP.NET samples with C# and VB source code [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I can suggest Excel
   Jetcell .NET component. It pretty
   Excel component. It does not use Jet
   drivers and excel automation. All
   information please find at:

> [http://www.devtriogroup.com/ExcelJetcell](http://www.devtriogroup.com/ExcelJetcell/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use EasyXLS. The component reads xls files from Excel 97 and xlsx/xlsb files from Excel 2007-2010.

[www.easyxls.com](http://www.easyxls.com)

You can find samples for how to use on their website.

Answer (score 0):

First - which version of Excel must you support? For example, xslx (2007) is just a zip file with xml files inside - so you should be able to use [#ZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) and xml generation / copying.

Another option is to write CSV and let the user import it - obviously more appropriate for data than for calculations.

There is also the 2003 xml-spreadsheet format - with contents like:

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"><Data ss:Type="Number">3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```

Pretty easy to create by hand...

Answer (score 0):

Where I work they have this one: http://www.syncfusion.com/products/xlsio/backoffice/default.aspx

Have used it a couple of times and it is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with aspose for a long time and can really recommend it.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.cells-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx

- Commercial product
- Great support
- Excel 97-2007
- 100% native .net